# How do I say this in English?

Tags: prepositions, word-order

What is the correct way to say this:

you got your dress on backwards OR you got your dress backwards on

Thanks in advance!

Comment: on goes before backwards

Comment: You have your dress on backwards.

Comment: If you say _backwards on_, you're saying it backwards.

Comment: @J.R. -- No, that would be "ti".

Comment: @HotLicks what?

Comment: @Taurus - "It" backwards.

Comment: @HotLicks I still don't get it :)

Comment: @Taurus -- Well, have some ti while you try to figure it out.

Comment: @HotLicks So, the "ti" stands for "tea", but how does that fit inside the joke ? I can't find any jokes in "If you say backwards on, you're saying ti backwards", what am I missing ? I don't really care about the joke by now, but we've come this far, let's not give up without coming to a resolution :)

Comment: @Taurus - "It backwards".  Think about it.

Comment: @HotLicks I presume you didn't allow such a subtlety to just pass about because you're a programmer ? More like I know you're a programmer because i viewed your profile an hour ago, but still, you noticed that because you're a programmer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say:

> You've got your dress on backwards.

Comment: 'have got' is poor English in America, where the passive participle of 'get' is 'gotten' rather than 'got'.  Just say "You have your dress on backwards."